# easier way to save sub-documents in separate collection in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got the following data structure:

```
const schema = new Schema({
  userId: { type: String, required: true },
  image: { type: String, required: true},
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  subCategories: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SubCategories' }]
}, {
  strict: 'throw'
});

export const Plan = mongoose.model('Plan', schema);


const schema = new Schema({
    userId: { type: String, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true }
}, {
    strict: 'throw'
});

export const SubCategories = mongoose.model('SubCategories', schema);
```

and I want to save each of the subCategories in a separate collection each time a new `Plan` entity is created.
This requires me to iterate the subCategories and to create each one of the sub-category.

for example:

```
plan.subCategories = await Promise.all(plan.subCategories.map(async (s: IWorkoutDay) => {
                const sub = new SubCategories(s);
                sub.userId = userId;
                await sub.save();
                return sub;
            }));

            const p = new Plan(plan);
            p.userId = userId;
            await p.save();
```

and also each time I want to edit the subCategories of the element I'm required to iterate find the element and to update each one separately.
is there an easier way to achieve this? since it seems pretty complicated to me.

Comment: Well that is how it works. You could simply call [`insertMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) or [`create()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) supplying the array of documents as data. The former is actually "one call" to the database and the latter is essentially "shorthand" for your code. You can also basically do `plan.subCategories.map( s => Object.assign(s,{ userId }) )` to "merge" before you instantiate. Also your `async` is not needed here since you don't call `await` "inside" the function.

Comment: @NeilLunn I was missing the await in the save part, so async is needed.  i'll try both of the methods.

Comment: So how do you think that changes what I told you? Use `insertMany()` or `create()`.